# How to find the mandatory fields on Sobjects in RestAPI /describe

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, sobject, fields, connected-apps

I am trying to create an oAuth based app that integrates with salesforce to create the objects from the app.

To let users know what all fields that users needs to put in at minimum to create the object the logic is as below:

if the field is createable &&  field is NOT nillable &&  (field is NOT DefaultedOnCreate  OR (field is DefaultedOnCreate AND field has default value as null))

Same thing we found on the forum  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008x86IAA
The best answer was that same logic chosen by the admin.

But for some objects this logic is is not correct,
e.g. to create a user this logic gives "IsStayInTouchRequired" as a mandatory field and it is not required by salesforce.

Please suggest the correct logic for finding the mandatory fields.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [Get Record Layout Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_record_layout.htm) to get the appropriate requireness per record type. This is part of the UI API.

Comment: Is there a list of object types that can be called using this API. e.g. invoking for email template and task gives error: Object Task is not supported in UI API"

Comment: @ThingworxSymphony there's an [API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_object_info_directory.htm#ui_api_resources_object_info_directory) for that.

Comment: This API is working for very few of the objects like account, lead, opportunity etc.  
But we need this information for all the sobjects like Folder, Task, Event etc..
Is there a way to achieve this?